# Django: Appending results on go

Tags: django, pandas, mongodb, dataframe, django-rest-framework

I have a program that fetches a very hugs data from database into data frames. loading the complete data is having "out of memory" issue. I want to return html(or json) response in loop i.e. for first loop some data is fetched and then return to html and then another loop is executed and appended to the existing html response and so on.
Is this possible? or is there an alternate way to accomplish this for a very high data.

Comment: use javascript https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Comment: Some more context would be useful, in particular: what is meant by "data frames"? Is this data intended to be displayed on the UI?

Comment: I used React(Next JS) to solve this issue. its fast and pre-renders the page.